# JPA @Transactional on a higher class from Jparepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I looked into the JpaRepository's save and delete methods and they're all annotated with `@Transactional`. Without sticking my own `@Transactional`s in on my service layer, calling save/delete on my own repositories derived from `JpaRepository` will result in the database with new rows saved (or deleted).

If I have 2 VOs that have their own respective repository DAOs which reference each other, and if I were to delete 1 - I should also delete the other. Would it be possible to override that Repository's `@Transactional` on the service layer so I am able to call .delete on both and have them in a single transaction?

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: DAOs should not reference each other. If you want to have a transaction involving several DAOs, then write a spring bean, annotate it with Transactional, and put the code in that spring bean.

Comment: JB Nizet is right - the trick here is that transactions will propagate from the service method to the DAO methods it invokes - so the same service transaction will include both delete calls, and they will be one txn.  But you must have thought about it, since you say "Without sticking my own @Transactional"  - so why would you not want to do that?

Comment: @moilejter I was just checking that Transactional annotations starts a transaction on the method highest in the stack, cheers.